# c++ and the type size_type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

The following code fragment fails to compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstddef.h>
#include <stddef.h>

using namespace std;
vector<int> list1{1,3,5,7,11};
size_type s1 = list1.size();
```

I am using the Microsoft Visual Stdio but I would not expect this to be compiler dependent. I believe the problem is that I am failing to include the correct header. What header should I be including?

Bob

Comment: You're certainly including headers you don't need, as well as headers that don't exist... `#include <cstddef.h> #include <stddef.h>`?

Comment: While we're at it, get rid of `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`size_type` is a dependent name of the container you are using.  You need

```
std::vector<int>::size_type
```

You could use `std::size_t` as that is what `size_type` generally boils down to but `std::vector<int>::size_type` is guaranteed to be correct.

If you are using C++11 or higher then you can forgot about this detail and just use

```
auto s1 = list1.size();
```

The compiler will deduce the correct type and if you ever change the container type this line does need to be changed.

Comment: Or, of course, `auto s1 = list1.size();` (if you're using C++11)

Comment: @rici I added that in.  It is good advice to advertise the use of auto.